# How can I do a shift in pandas based on conditonal values?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do some feature engineering and one of the ideas I'm testing is adding previous obvseration as a column within the dataframe.  I know .shift() can do that in pandas but the problem is I only watch it shifted if it matches a certain condition.

```
# add new column for previous value
df_labeled = df_labeled.sort_values(by=['ticker', 'periodDate']) #this ensures data/date are in order
df_labeled['lastValue'] = df_labeled['value'].shift(1) #add's previous value to current row
df_labeled[['ticker', 'periodDate', 'value', 'lastValue']]
```

It works for the first item:

```
ticker  periodDate  value   lastValue
    Abc 2010    121000.0    NaN
    Abc 2011    125700.0    121000.0
    xyz 2010    125000.0    125700.0
    xyz 2011    125700.0    125000.0
```

as you can see, xyz should be NaN but instead, it's the previous value of the last item before it in the dataframe.

Is there a way to conditionally set it? i.e. if `df_labeled['ticker'] == df_labeled['ticker'].shift(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to shift `value` column based on `ticker` column:

```
df['lastValue'] = df.groupby(['ticker'], as_index=False)['value'].shift(1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  ticker  periodDate     value  lastValue
0    Abc        2010  121000.0        NaN
1    Abc        2011  125700.0   121000.0
2    xyz        2010  125000.0        NaN
3    xyz        2011  125700.0   125000.0
```

Comment: wow. thanks. I was looking up a nested loop or lambda approach to this. This is easier and looks beautiful. Thank you.